# CMake w/ARM tools _start symbol undefined

Tags: gcc, cmake, linker, arm, startup

I build an executable file thru CMake. The executable is linked to various static libraries, also built thru CMake in the same project. However, linking is not happening properly.

I run `arm-none-eabi objdump -tT executable` and see that symbols `_start` and many of the other functions that I define are undefined.

This is the main `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE DEBUG)

# Set C/C++ compile and linking flags
set(GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS "-march=armv7e-m -mthumb \
-mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -Og -fmessage-length=0 \
-fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -ffreestanding \
-fno-move-loop-invariants -Wall -Wextra -g3")

set(GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS
"-T \"${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/ldscripts/mem.ld\" \
-T \"${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/ldscripts/libs.ld\" \
-T \"${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/ldscripts/sections.ld\" \
-nostartfiles -Xlinker --gc-sections -Wl,-Map,\"elka.map\" \
--specs=nano.specs")
#--specs=nano.specs -o \"elka.elf\"")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS}")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS}")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER__FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS}")

set(ELKA_LINK_LIBS "")

add_definitions(-DUSE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER)

# Add libraries, subdirectories, etc to include all source and header files
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc
${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc/CMSIS
${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc/Device/STM32F4xx
${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc/drivers
${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc/elka_hal
${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc/FreeRTOS
${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc/FreeRTOS/GCC/ARM_CM4F
${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc/modules
${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc/nvicconf
${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver
${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc/utils
)

add_subdirectory(src)

#FIXME make sure that this will create elka executable file
#TODO link against libraries
add_executable(elka
  src/main.c
  src/_write.c
)

add_dependencies(elka
  ${ELKA_LINK_LIBS}
)
```

There are other `CMakeLists.txt` files in subdirectories. They serve to build the static libraries and add them to the `ELKA_LINK_LIBS` variable. The main `CMakeLists.txt` file generates the following command in CMake. to perform linking, followed by the warning:

```
/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc   -march=armv7e-m -mthumb -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -Og -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -ffreestanding -fno-move-loop-invariants -Wall -Wextra -g3 -g   -T /Programs/elka/elka_firmware/elka_firmware/ldscripts/mem.ld -T /Programs/elka/elka_firmware/elka_firmware/ldscripts/libs.ld -T /Programs/elka/elka_firmware/elka_firmware/ldscripts/sections.ld -nostartfiles -Xlinker --gc-sections -Wl,-Map,elka.map --specs=nano.specs CMakeFiles/elka.dir/src/main.c.obj CMakeFiles/elka.dir/src/_write.c.obj  -o elka src/drivers/libelka_drivers.a src/elka_hal/libelka_hal.a src/FreeRTOS/libFreeRTOS.a src/modules/libelka_modules.a src/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/libSTM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver.a src/utils/libelka_utils.a
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000008000028
```

Why is `_start` undefined, first of all? If that is a trivial answer, then why are the other symbols in this executable undefined? I can post the `objdump` or other files if pertinent.

In a final note, I have found that the symbols for functions that I have defined in other libraries are undefined in those other static libraries. Below is a sample `CMakeLists.txt` for one library:

```
# src/elka_hal
include_directories(
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc/elka_hal
)

add_library(elka_hal STATIC
    imu.c
)

set(ELKA_LINK_LIBS 
  ${ELKA_LINK_LIBS} elka_hal
  PARENT_SCOPE
)
```

Edit: It seems to link symbols correctly if I take away the `-nostartfiles` flag from `GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS` and change `--specs=nano.specs` to `--specs=nosys.specs`

Comment: Are you sure this is the right toolchain? For example, did you need one that includes `libc` libraries instead, like `arm-none-linux-gnueabi`?

Comment: Wouldn't it be `arm-linux-gnueabi`? Source: https://wiki.linaro.org/WorkingGroups/ToolChain/FAQ#What_is_the_differences_between_.2BIBw-arm-none-eabi-.2BIB0_and_.2BIBw-arm-linux-gnueabihf.2BIB0.3F_Can_I_use_.2BIBw-arm-linux-gnueabihf.2BIB0_tool_chain_in_bare-metal_environment.3F_How_do_you_know_which_toolchain_binary_to_use_where.3F

Comment: It compiles, though, so which libraries would it be using? I'm compiling for use with `FreeRTOS`

Comment: It seems to be using `/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/libgcc.a` and `/usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libg_nano.a`. The last one because I specify `--specs=nano.specs` in the linker flags.